# Android contact programmed sync

Tags: android, synchronization, edit, contacts

I set up an account manager for my application which syncs contacts from my cloud service to the device. The account shows up under Accounts & Sync along with other such accounts (Google, FB, ...). After logged in it syncs web contacts to your device. The contacts are linked to that account. They are added using batch operations using the example from the android developer webpage.

The problem I'm facing is that once synced the contacts can be edited, but the user can edit only the name (I'm transferring email and phone numbers too). The syncadapter has the property

```
android:supportsUploading="true"
```

enabled, but it only allows editing of the name. If the property is set to false the contact cannot be edited at all.

I would really appreciate some help, since it's been bugging me for days now.

Comment: in fact there is a work around you can make.
The example is for insertion but I'm pretty sure it works for editing .
here the post :
http://stackoverflow.com/a/11153652/1195001 You need to make your own modification activity with all the fields you want to edit (some people take the one from aosp source and clean it from private reference).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok,

so to answer my own question. You can't. You can only edit name and photo if a contact is not a Google or Exchange contact.