# Edit Android Sync adapter's contacts

Tags: android, contacts, adapter, synchronization, edit

One year ago I developed a sync adapter for Android.
At that time it wasn't possible to show a custom activity or to customize the standard activity to edit a contact.
The result was that, although it was possible to configure the synch adapter in a such a way that the added contacts where editable, to edit a contact was not really feasible, unless the custom contacts were the same as the normal ones.

Is it still like that? Did google fix the problem?

See for a reference:
http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/msg/86d4d895e88a5ebb

I found this: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/msg/85f9304dfcc4e284

but it does not say where to find the documentation

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround catching an intent to launch your own activity.
you need to modify a bit the following example but it works very well (on 2.3.x and 4.0.X) for me for insertion.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11153652/1195001

Comment: Hi. Thank-you but that is not the answer. What I was looking for was a way to edit a contact while the shown method is just a way to open a custom dialog when the user asks to insert a new contact